# Insert html code in ckeditor startup instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create template for CkEditor, when CKEditor will start it will load with some predefined format,

Here is initialization of Ckeditor,

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1');
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(template);
```

I am creating script tag in HTML file at load,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var template = '
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                    <textarea name="test"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                    <textarea name="test1"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
</script>
```

When page is loading it will end with `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"`

I think some syntax\string problem in template variable,

How can i pass HTML code as a string variable?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(\''+ template +'\');
```